# MiniDIsplay Port to USB-C with Power?

Tags: power, display-port, usb-c

I have a Thinkpad X1 Yoga, first generation. It has a DisplayPort but no USB-C ports.

I want to buy an external monitor, like the [ThinkVision M14](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/thinkvisionM14) that passes both video and power trough it's USB-C port.

Is there any cable that would allow me to connect the ThinkPad Yoga Gen1 to the [ThinkVision M14](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/thinkvisionM14)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, because I just read from other people who had success with this: Wacom Link Plus (ACK42819). The guy in question claims that he successfully connected a Thinkvision M14 to a DisplayPort using this device. Source, last post in this thread: https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/usb-c-monitor-eingang-zu-displayport-kabel.1839101/

Comment: Go to https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/thinkvisionM14, click on the chat pop-up at lower right, and ask Lenovo if they have an adapter device or know of one which would work. Since both the laptop and the display are Lenovo, their answer would be trustworthy.

Comment: *"Is there any cable..."* -- This definitely won't be a cable because DisplayPort and USB-C aren't wire-to-wire compatible with each other. You'll be looking for a box-like adapter, and something like that Wacom Link Plus looks promising. Generally the USB-C displays require USB-C computers, so look for a monitor that has a separate HDMI or DisplayPort input.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. While the Wacom Link Plus suggested by @user13807 was a great help, by itself wasn't enough.

**You will need to:**

1. Use a WACON Link Plus dongle
2. Buy an additional USB 3.0 to USB-C cable (ex: Anker PowerLine+ USB-C to USB 3.0 cable) - although the Wacon dongle brings a USB-A to micro USB cable, you should replace it by this one (USB 3.0 to USB-C) as the former is not enough to power the monitor

With this in hand, you can easily connect the M14 to a laptop that has a USB 3.0 connector and a mini DisplayPort.